# Unable to merge all partitions (including the Recovery partition) in my Old Laptop hard drive turned external drive

Tags: windows, partitioning, external-hard-drive, disk-management

I have the hard drive of my laptop that was replaced with a SSD so I wanted to use it as an external storage space by combining them all into one. There were 3 partitions previously that I formatted and deleted but am still left with 2 different unallocated partitions.
[image: the current partitions.]

I tried creating one of them into a Simple disk and then extending it.  But on clicking that a pop-up appears telling me I'll have to convert it into Dynamic disk. On clicking next, a pop-up appears saying "*Operation not supported by the object"*.

Also, there are two Health Recovery Partitions and 1 EFI System Partition. (probably from their time as the primary storage and not useful now from what I've understood.) Should I get these spaces converted into a single space too or not bother about them? And if the former, how? Because the only option I can see on right-clicking on these is "Help".
Help me out with this.

Comment: For use as an external data only drive you certainly don't need neither an EFI partition nor recovery partitions. Better to delete them all and create a new single partition. Merging partitions in this context is nonsensical.

Comment: You can’t merge the 148GB partition and 315GB partition without third party’s software unless you delete the recovery partition with Disk Manager.

Comment: @Ramhound there's no option to delete this recovery partition in the disk management though.

Comment: Use CLI tools instead. Or just boot a Linux live session. Any mainstream Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) will have GParted ready. Open it then Devices menu > Create new partition table... (optional here but better to choose GPT anyway), apply and ALL data will be gone. Now you can create and format partitions (probably better just one as NTFS or exFAT to use with Windows). That's all.

Comment: @ChatrapalSinghRathore - You don’t need to delete it. Just move it to the end of the disk.  Furthermore, the limit of not being able to delete the recovery partition, only exists with Disk Manager. You can also just format the entire disk, and reallocate a single partition, nothing you do to that disk should not be done without a backup

Comment: Just reiterating what @ChanganAuto stated: 1. Remove *all* partitions, creating ~500 GB free space. Commit that action. 2. Create a single partition. 3. Format as you wish, likely NTFS for Windows (and that can also be read by Linux). The whole process should take just a minute, as opposed to moving partitions, which takes hours and is hard on the SSD.

Comment: You could use a third-party partition editor to delete the EFI and Recovery partitions. Or just format the disk if you don't need the data.